# How do I use an Airflow variable inside a Databricks notebook?

Tags: pyspark, airflow, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks PySpark notebook that gets called from an Airflow DAG.
I created a variable in Airflow by going to Admin - Variables and added a key-value pair.

I cannot find a way to use that Airflow variable in Databricks.

Edit to add sample of my code.

```
notebook_task = {
    'notebook_path': '/Users/email@exaple.com/myDAG',
    'base_parameters': {
        "token": token
    }
}
```

and the operator defined here

```
opr_submit_run = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='run_notebook',
    existing_cluster_id='xxxxx', 
    run_name='test',
    databricks_conn_id='databricks_xxx',  
    notebook_task=notebook_task
)
```

What ended up working is using base_parameters instead of notebook_parans which can be found here https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html

and accessing it from databricks by using

```
my_param = dbutils.widgets.get("token")
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant operator code? Are you using the operator from databricks provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the answer provided by Alex since this question was asked in the context of Apache-Airflow that executing a databricks notebook.

The `DatabricksRunNowOperator` (which is available by the [databricks provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/)) has `notebook_params` that is a dict from keys to values for jobs with notebook task, e.g. `"notebook_params": {"name": "john doe", "age":  "35"}`. The map is passed to the notebook and will be accessible through the
`dbutils.widgets.get` function. As Alex explained you can access the value from databricks notebook as:

```
my_param = dbutils.widgets.get("key")
```

An example usage will be:

```
spark_jar_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='spark_jar_task',
    new_cluster=new_cluster,
    notebook_params={"name": "john doe", "age":  "35"},
    spark_jar_task={'main_class_name': 'com.example.ProcessData'},
    libraries=[{'jar': 'dbfs:/lib/etl-0.1.jar'}],
)
```

The issue now is how to pass a value from Airflow Variable rather than a static value. For that we need the `notebook_params` to be a templated field so the Jinja engine will template the value. The problem is that `notebook_params` is not listed in the [template_fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/866a601b76e219b3c043e1dbbc8fb22300866351/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks.py#L454)
To overcome this we can create a custom version of the operator as:

```
class MyDatabricksRunNowOperator(DatabricksRunNowOperator):
    template_fields = DatabricksRunNowOperator.template_fields + ('notebook_params',)
```

Then we can use [macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables) `{{ var.value.my_var }}` which will be templated during run time as:

```
spark_jar_task = MyDatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='spark_jar_task',
    new_cluster=new_cluster,
    notebook_params={"var_value": {{ var.value.my_var }} },
    spark_jar_task={'main_class_name': 'com.example.ProcessData'},
    libraries=[{'jar': 'dbfs:/lib/etl-0.1.jar'}],
)
```

The operator will get the value of `my_var` Variable and pass it to your notebook.

Comment: @ggofthejungle copy paste mistake.. fixed

Comment: Hey @Elad thank you for the very detailed response. I ended up getting it to work by adding my variable to base_parameters instead of notebook_params. Where would I declare class MyDatabricksRunNowOperator(DatabricksRunNowOperator):
? In a different file or the same file as the rest of the airflow code?

Comment: I don't know what is base_parameters there is no such parameter for this operator but I'm glad it worked for you. If you are not using notebook_params then you don't need the custom operator.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it is very detailed. I ended up using the dbutils.widgets.get("key") but base_parameters worked for me while notebook_params did not. You can find base_parameters defined here - https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html  Sorry I am very new to airflow and databricks so I don't fully understand the difference between notebook_params and base_parameters.

Answer (score 4):

if you set it as a parameter to the notebook call (parameters inside `notebook_task`), then  you need to use [the dbutils.widgets.get function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html), put at the beginning of notebook something like this:

```py
my_param = dbutils.widgets.get("key")
```

Comment: Indeed. You have to make sure to pass the variable onto the Databricks notebook with the invocation of the notebook.